# What a Message format is this

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

[image]

I've been looking for a solution for this message format for about 6 weeks.
I copied the message format from the Chrome devtools from a WebSocket connection.

The message looks like this:

```
%xt%EmpireEx_2%ssi%1%{"TX":438,"TY":1218,"KID":1}%
```

What does the `%` mean here?

It's a JSON format. Since in Fiddler I can see it as a JSON. But how would you send something like this as JSON?

Unfortunately I can't get any further.

I tried sending it with `json.stringify` but to no avail. I can't get any further with `JsonParse`, either. Since the `%` sign always triggers an error.

I didn't get any further with `decodeUri` & `encodeUri`, either.

Comment: It is not JSON. Looks like websocket string data to a gaming site. I found this https://bytemeta.vip/repo/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/667

Comment: A websocket connection to what exactly? It's some format that something understands, but it could be anything. It's not necessarily any kind of standard, it could be proprietary.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your answer, it's exactly about the game where such a special format is used.

Comment: So you would not send it as JSON. So `let new_message = \`%xt%EmpireEx_2%ssi%1%{"TX":438,"TY":1218,"KID":1}%\`; socket.emit('new_message', new_message);` or whatever you use to send

Comment: What I don't understand is when I parse the data with Fiddler, I can display it as Json format.
Sending was the smaller problem :-)

If there should be a solution how to work with JsonStringify and JsonParse here, I would like to hear from you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipEj6.png

Comment: So show as JSON instead of text. If you want it as JSON and Fiddler reads it as JSON why not click the JSON tab?

Comment: I would like to do it via my own websocket connection. If I get the server response as Json, I can only output specific values ​​and not everything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@ Community Bot

This is the server response.
The answer is Binary Blob, which I can't parse with Json. Here I am currently using the file reader.
The output as text looks like this

%xt%cat%1%0%{"A":{"M":{"MID":966277816,"PT":0,"TT":15,"D":1,"TID":6470797,"T":2,"HBW":1009,"KID":0,"TA":[1,111,11,7668107,6470797,6,5,5,5,5,"xxxxxxx",0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,[],0],"SID":-213,"OID":6470797,"SA":[2,112,760,-1,793,10800,0]},"UM":{"PWD":0,"TWD":0,"L":{"ID":0,"WID":2,"VIS":0,"N":"Feldherr 25","GID":104,"L":10,"W":7318,"D":15,"SPR":2997,"EQ":[[14607103832,1,2,5,-1,[[4,84,[118.2]],[5,36,[75.8]],[113,24,[8.6]],[108,80,[42.0]]],-1,-1,20,-1,-1,3,[1,6,3240,[7589481,31,7,3580,[[205,81,[12.0]],[204,91,[6.5]],[207,86,[6.3]]],0]]],[14607103758,2,2,5,-1,[[1,72,[85.6]],[2,39,[83.9]],[117,82,[37.8]],[118,43,[7.0]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[2,6,3360,[7589726,31,7,3490,[[202,85,[43.5]],[203,84,[6.2]],[205,80,[11.9]]],0]]],[14607103142,3,2,5,-1,[[3,63,[117.8]],[6,56,[77.4]],[108,38,[25.8]],[113,56,[14.0]]],-1,-1,26,-1,-1,3,[3,5,3130,[7589401,31,7,3760,[[201,97,[13.7]],[202,95,[47.2]],[205,84,[12.3]]],0]]],[14607103806,4,2,5,-1,[[7,56,[14.8]],[121,89,[215,891.0]],[114,22,[10.1]],[117,32,[17.8]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[4,4,2990,[7589831,31,7,3550,[[202,86,[43.9]],[208,80,[17.9]],[205,89,[12.8]]],0]]],[14616963754,6,2,15,-1,[[705,92,[16.9]],[702,97,[41.1]],[704,97,[29.3]],[20011,93,[2060,34.0,2061,34.0,2062,34.0,2063,34.0,2064,34.0,2065,34.0,2066,34.0,2067,34.0,2068,34.0,148,34.0,2069,34.0,149,34.0,2070,34.0,150,34.0,151,34.0,2071,34.0,2072,34.0,2073,34.0,2074,34.0,2075,34.0,2076,34.0,2077,34.0,2078,34.0,2079,34.0,2020,34.0,2021,34.0,2022,34.0,2023,34.0,2024,34.0,2025,34.0,2026,34.0,2027,34.0,2028,34.0,2029,34.0,2030,34.0,2031,34.0,2032,34.0,2033,34.0,2034,34.0,2035,34.0,2036,34.0,2037,34.0,2038,34.0,2039,34.0]],[20006,96,[620,116.0]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[64,7,3860,[]]]],"GASAIDS":[],"SIDS":[104022],"AE":[]}},"A":[[10,340]],"G":[["W",16403],["S",10327],["F",34021],["C1",34946],["C2",20],["I",3338]],"S":0},"O":[{},{"OID":6470797,"DUM":false,"N":"xxxxxx","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":70,"LL":950,"H":1658,"AVP":51770,"CF":154647,"HF":122152837,"PRE":13,"SUF":16,"TOPX":-1,"MP":13469319,"R":0,"AID":72962,"AR":8,"AN":"xxxx","aee":{"CF":38038704317,"BGT":7,"BGC1":11993088,"BGC2":1644825,"BGC3":1644825,"SPT":1,"S1":9,"SC1":14408394,"S2":-1,"SC2":-1,"S3":-1,"SC3":-1},"RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7668107,111,567,1],[1,7678578,421,592,12],[2,7677919,455,894,12],[3,7678795,876,875,12]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1}]}%

My Problem is ' % ' at the beginning & End.
This always throws an error when I want to parse the blob data with json.
I would like only certain data from the answer and not everything. I can help myself with Json. I can't get any further with this format alone.
I am now looking for a solution on how I can process this data.

Comment: It looks like a JSON document *inside* of some other `%`-delimited framing protocol. You would have to strip off the framing first, then you can parse the rest as JSON.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau        Thanks for your answer. If I delete it manually, you're right. It's a json. Now I have to get it to work automatically. Since I need to pass received data to a function.

If you have an idea, I would be happy

Comment: You need to know the format you are dealing with, before you can parse it.  You can't just strip off portions without understanding what they are.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you-

```
A = '%xt%csm%1%0%{"A":{"M":{"MID":566968948,"PT":0,"TT":6,"D":1,"TID":6470797,"T":3,"HBW":-1,"KID":0,"TA":[1,935,59,7668107,6470797,6,5,5,5,5,"Burg DjangoJack",0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,[],0],"SID":-601,"OID":6470797,"SA":[27,936,59,0,0,-1670942678,0,-601,971,110,112,36]},"S":{"SC":46,"ST":0,"SA":100,"SR":2}},"O":[{"OID":6470797,"DUM":false,"N":"DjangoJack","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":70,"LL":950,"H":1658,"AVP":51770,"CF":151554,"HF":122152837,"PRE":13,"SUF":16,"TOPX":-1,"MP":2469047,"R":0,"AID":22962,"AR":8,"AN":"RAWSIDE","aee":{"CF":38038704317,"BGT":7,"BGC1":11993088,"BGC2":1644825,"BGC3":1644825,"SPT":1,"S1":9,"SC1":14408394,"S2":-1,"SC2":-1,"S3":-1,"SC3":-1},"RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7668107,935,59,1],[1,7678578,421,592,12],[2,7677919,455,894,12],[3,7678795,876,875,12]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1,"RNP":-1},{"OID":6470797,"DUM":false,"N":"DjangoJack","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":70,"LL":950,"H":1658,"AVP":51770,"CF":151554,"HF":122152837,"PRE":13,"SUF":16,"TOPX":-1,"MP":2469047,"R":0,"AID":22962,"AR":8,"AN":"RAWSIDE","aee":{"CF":38038704317,"BGT":7,"BGC1":11993088,"BGC2":1644825,"BGC3":1644825,"SPT":1,"S1":9,"SC1":14408394,"S2":-1,"SC2":-1,"S3":-1,"SC3":-1},"RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7668107,935,59,1],[1,7678578,421,592,12],[2,7677919,455,894,12],[3,7678795,876,875,12]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1,"RNP":-1}]}%'
B = A.replace('%xt%csm%1%0%',"");
C = B.replace('%',"");
obj = JSON.parse(C);
```

I'm open to further suggestions.